# How to create reusable UI with variable template?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I want to do something like this:

**Component file:**

```
<template name="drop_down">
    <span class="dropdown">
        {{> primary_element}} <--- load the template named button
        <span class="dropdown-panel">
            {{> panel_template}} <--- load the template named button_panel
        </span>
    </span>
</template>
```

**Usage:**

```
{{> drop_down primary_element="button" panel_template="button_panel"}}
<template name="button"> some styled button </template>
<template name="button_panel"> panel content </template>
```

and then I can reuse it just like this

```
{{> drop_down primary_element="tmp_btn_2" panel_template="tmp_panel_2"}}
    <template name="tmp_btn_2"> another button style </template>
    <template name="tmp_panel_2"> other panel content </template>
```

Comment: it will come through to the template as the data variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [dynamic templates](https://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic). In blaze you can pass in the template to be used as a variable, as well as the data context itself. They are quite flexible.

For example:

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=whichTemplate data=myData }}
```

This would refer to the `whichTemplate` helper to figure out which template to use and would get the data context from the `myData` helper. i.e. both the choice of template and the choice of data come from *variables*.

In your case you are trying to use two dynamic templates in the context of your `dropdown` template. You can do:

```
<template name="drop_down">
  {{#with myElements}}
    <span class="dropdown">
      {{> Template.dynamic template=this.primary}}
      <span class="dropdown-panel">
        {{> Template.dynamic template=this.panel}}
      </span>
    </span>
{{/with}}
</template
```

Then your `myElements` helper just needs to return the names of the templates to use as *strings*, ex:

```
Template.dropdown.helpers({
  myElements() {

    let p1 = "button";  // compute these two based on your own logic
    let p2 = "button_panel";

    return {primary: p1, panel: p2 };
  }
});
```

Comment: can you put an example in your answer ?

Comment: thank you that's what I was looking for but in the myElement it should return || primary: this.primary_element, panel: this.panel_template || so i can use it dynamicaly.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of having it in a function, you can return whatever you need.